# How to upload a file in Node.js ? Error: Cannot POST /upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, ejs

**PROBLEM:**

I click on submit in my upload.ejs and I get the error: "Cannot POST /upload"

---

**SOLUTION:**

My problem was an architectural one more than a coding problem.

I changed the structure of my project to solve the problem.

I created a new file called "upload.js" to put the router code in.

I also moved the "upload.ejs" to the root of the project.

I updated my "app.js" to take into account the new router file "upload.js".

I changed the form to use "upload.js".

---

**CODE:**

upload.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var flash = require("connect-flash");

var firebase = require("firebase");

var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({dest:"./public/images/uploads/"});

router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    res.render("upload");
});

router.post("/", upload.single("image"), function(req, res, next){

    if (req.file){
        console.log("Uploading file...");
        var image = req.file.filename;
    }
    else {
        console.log("No file uploaded");
        var image = "noimage.jpg";
    }

    var post = {
        title: req.body.title,
        section: req.body.section,
        image: image,
    }

    var section = req.body.section.toLowerCase();

    firebase.database().ref("posts/"+section).push(post);

    req.flash("success_msg", "Post Created");
    res.redirect("/upload");


});

module.exports = router;
```

upload.ejs

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload">
```

Comment: shouldn't you post at /users/upload according to your routes?

Comment: @AbhyuditJain I tried, doesnt' work. I get: Cannot POST /users/upload

Comment: Why did you remove all the code from your question?  This renders the question worthless as a reference for others since there is not enough information in the question any more to even know what was being asked.  I guess this question should just be deleted now as it stands.  Or, you could put the relevant code back into the question so it retains some usefulness for others.  Also, if you find an answer to your own question, you post your own answer - you don't put that in the question.  Questions are for questions, answers are for answers (unlike some other sites).

Comment: @jfriend00 I contacted a moderator to delete the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for reminding me :)

Comment: You can delete your own question.  You do not need a moderator.  There should be a delete link right below your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am going to edit my question.

Comment: Questions should NOT contain your answer here on stack overflow.  Questions are questions.  Answers are answers.  If you want to share your answer, then post an answer to your own question (that is perfectly acceptable here).

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually, it is quite common practice to post the answer inside the question if the answer was found quickly. The reason for that being it takes 48 hours to accept your own answer :) Also, people may be looking for the correct answer but it is not guaranteed your answer will be the one showing on top. But, otherwise, I agree with you.

Comment: It is not quite common and it is not the right practice here.  That's not how this site is set up to work.  After 48 hours, you can accept your answer and it will show as the first answer then.   If other people choose to post answers, then that will be because they think they have a better answer than you provided (which should be perfectly fine).

Comment: I already chose someone's answer and I am not taking back what I have given :) But I agree with you.

Comment: @jfriend00 Btw, I see you have expertise in Javascript. Do you think you have an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069910/how-to-register-a-user-in-firebase-using-node-js  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are POSTing to `/upload` url but you the route that you register is POST `/users/upload`. Possibly you have to move the follwing function into the routes/index.js file:

```
router.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), function(req, res, next){

    if (req.file){
        console.log("Uploading file...");
        var image = req.file.filename;
    }
    else {
        console.log("No file uploaded");
        var image = "noimage.jpg";
    }

    var post = {
        title: req.body.title,
        section: req.body.section,
        image: image,
    }

    var postRef = fbRef.child("posts");

    postRef.push().set(post);

    req.flash("success_msg", "Post Created")
    res.redirect("/"+ req.body.section.toLowerCase());

});
```

Comment: Tried. No success :(

Comment: I ended up rethinking the architecture of my project and created a new file called "upload.js" to put the router code in. I also moved the "upload.ejs" to the root of the project. I updated my "app.js" to take into account the new router file "upload.js". Your answer put me in the right direction though. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

You need to use multer module:
server.js

```
multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer({
        dest: './public/uploads/',
        rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
            return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        }
}));
```

upload.js

```
router.post("/upload",function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

Comment: can you post your code here? I think something is wrong in your code

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding :) I was already using multer. Thanks for the answer though !